# Page Generation Time for Human-Friendly Format

Tags: php

```
function PageStartTime() {
        $time = microtime();
        $time = explode(' ', $time);
        $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
        $start = $time;
    }

function pageFinishTime() {
        $time = microtime();
        $time = explode(' ', $time);
        $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
        $finish = $time;
        $total_time = round(($finish - $start), 1);
        echo "Page generated in $total_time seconds.";
        echo 'Peak memory usage: ',round(memory_get_peak_usage()/1048576, 2), 'MB';
    }
```

Print:

> Page generated in 1473241297.4 seconds.Peak memory usage: 0.56MB

How I can change `"human-friendly"` format?

Comment: How I can change "human-friendly" format? what is mean by `human-friendly`? an example?

Comment: "1473241297.4" -> 1.4 Sec @Anant

Comment: Thank you for interest. Do I have my opportunity to turn this format (1.4 sec..)? @Anant

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure are you using class or not but if not you must have some reference to the $start time;

```
private $start = 0;

function PageStartTime() {
    $this->start = microtime(true);
}

function pageFinishTime() {
        $finish = microtime(true);
        $total_time = round(($finish - $this->start), 4);
        echo "Page generated in $total_time seconds.";
        echo 'Peak memory usage: ',round(memory_get_peak_usage()/1048576, 2), 'MB';
    }
```

Comment: Print: "1473243582.1171"

Comment: thisresult is current finish result, try to var_dump start time there should be almos the same value, but I assume that your start value is 0

Comment: @Saracoglu  you marked my answer then unmarked it. why? can i know the reason?